# One definition rule warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have been bitten by a nasty "one definition rule" violation.
I am now afraid of having lots of subtle bugs in my projects.

For example, the following program will result in a null pointer dereference with visual studio 2015:

```
Source1.cpp:
----------
struct S {
    double d = 0;
};

void Foo() {
    S s;
}


Source2.cpp:
-----------
struct S {
    int a = 0;
};

int main() {

    int value = 5;
    int& valueRef = value;
    S s;           // valueRef is erased due to S::d initialization from Source1.cpp

    valueRef++;    // crash
}
```

This compiles with no warnings.

It's nasty because `Source2.cpp` doesn't even use anything from `Source1.cpp`. If I remove `Source1.cpp` from the project, it still compiles, and there is no problem anymore.

In large projects, it seems very hard to ensure that no cpp file "locally" define a struct or class with an already defined name.

I have some classes such as `Point`, `Serie`, `State`, `Item`, ... I though this was OK in small cpp files, but I realize it's not safe.

Is there a compiler warning to catch such bugs ?
If not, what are the best practices to avoid ODR violation ?

Comment: Define them in an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, at the very bottom the ODR violation (which actually leads to the problem you are observing) is the implicitly-defined *inline* constructor of class `S`. Your program has two non-matching versions of inline `S::S()` function, which can be seen as another ODR violation induced by the original ODR violation (i.e. same class defined differently).

It would be difficult for the implementation to "see" this error in the current approach to the C++ compilation infrastructure. Of course, it is possible to do with sufficient effort.

In this case in order to make the error "visible" you can explicitly declare and define the class constructor as a non-inline function with empty body. Presence of two non-inline `S::S()` will trigger a linker error.

Understandably, you might see this as an overly artificial measure, unacceptable in some cases since it might change the "aggregate" status of the class.

Answer (score 5):

> If not, what are the best practices to avoid ODR violation ?

This is fundamentally why we have namespaces.

Use one well-known namespace per software component (e.g. `boost`, `std`, `asio`, `sql`, `mytool`, `yourlib` etc).

A name's namespace actually forms part of its name, so the following:

```
namespace X {
  struct S {};
}

namespace Y {
  struct S {};
}

struct S {};
```

results in three distinct classes being defined. One is called `X::S`, one is called `Y::S` and the other is `S`, also known as `::S`.

`::` is the *global namespace*. Avoiding declaring names here is a good idea since any C components you use in your program (or naively-written c++ components) will quickly pollute this namespace with their own names.

Answer (score 4):

- it is not hard to organize class/struct names, even with millions of codes, with powerful `namespace`. Do not forget that `namespace` can define nested levels
- if you really want some definition "locally", try anonymous `namespace`
- i remember that the standard explicitly does not require any diagnostics if the programmer violates ODR, so count on ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

[cppcheck](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/) will detect ODR violations, and can be [integrated into Visual Studio](https://duleekag.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-integrate-cppcheck-with.html).

Here's a quick command line invocation using cppcheck ver 2.6 to find an ODR:

```
cppcheck classes/config/foo.cpp
```

Output:

```
classes/config/foo.h:15:1: error: The one definition rule is violated, different classes/structs have the same name 'MyClass' [ctuOneDefinitionRuleViolation]
class MyClass
^
classes/config/foo.h:60:1: note: The one definition rule is violated, different classes/structs have the same name 'MyClass'
class MyClass
^
classes/config/foo.h:15:1: note: The one definition rule is violated, different classes/structs have the same name 'MyClass'
class MyClass
^
```

Note that properly catching all ODRs [requires the ability to
see the full application source at once](https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc888857/m2/1/high_res_d/898014.pdf)--full program analysis. So, cppcheck and other static analyzers may give false positives or miss some violations. However, this is an easy FOSS way to hunt for possibly problematic program constructs.